# Is there a datetime ± infinity?

Tags: python, sql, django, datetime

For floats we have special objects like -inf (and +inf), and which are guaranteed to compare less than (and greater than) other numbers.

I need something similar for datetimes, is there any such thing?  In-db ordering must work correctly with django queryset filters, and ideally it should be db-agnostic (but at the very least it must work with mysql and sqlite) and timezone-agnostic.

At the moment I'm using null/`None`, but it is creating very messy queries because `None` is doing the job of *both* -inf and +inf and I have to explicitly account for all those cases in the queries.

Comment: The dates are usually stored as the platform's integer (second resolution) or integer + integer structure (to give subsecond resolution), meaning you have an upper and lower limit, but not special "inf", "NaN", etc., which are actually encoded in the floating point standard.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.max
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
```

You can get `min`/`max` for `datetime`, `date`, and `time`.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this is not compatible with tz-aware datetime objects.

Comment: This do not work with `pandas`.

Answer (score 29):

There isn't; the best you have is the [`datetime.datetime.min`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.min) and [`datetime.datetime.max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.max) values.

These are guaranteed to be the smallest and largest `datetime` values, but `datetime.datetime.min == datetime.datetime.min` is still `True`; everything else is larger. The inverse is true for the `datatime.datetime.max` value.

There are also `min` and `max` values for `datetime.date` and `datetime.time`.

Comment: How db-agnostic are these?

Comment: @wim: these are *`datetime` objects*; if you are passing `datetime` objects to your Django queries now, these are no different. They are simply the smallest and largest `datetime` objects you can create.

Comment: So they are the smallest and largest no matter what platform, db, timezone?

Comment: They are the smallest and largest that *Python* can produce. They are naive datetime objects, no timezone attached. If you have to attach a timezone, use UTC.

Comment: It is probably still possible that these values might turn out outside of the underlying database's range (so comparisons against them as constants might fail), or that the database can represent (and might contain) datetimes outside this range. Might be good to give consideration to such cases.

Comment: @lanzz: At which point Django cannot work with those **anyway**; it relies on the `datetime` module to handle all datetime values stored in the database.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `WHERE datetime_field < $unrepresentable_date` might behave in an undefined way or not work at all, even without needing Django to actually load such values in models.

Comment: I am scared to use these because the mysql docs say that years start at 1000 not at 0001:   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: @wim I've tested MySQL 5.5, and although it contradicts the documentation, datetimes all the way back to `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000` are supported. Still, this might be an unreliable feature that might disappear in an upgrade.

Comment: @lanzz: I *think* that MySQL treats dates that it cannot support as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` instead, unless in strict mode. That works out for range queries though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters nope, `SELECT cast('0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000' AS datetime)` returns a `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000` result, not 0000

Comment: @lanzz: indeed; comparisons also work correctly for dates before the year 1000; at least on my 5.6 setup. Seems like the documentation is out of date there.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is using dates in Pandas dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Timestamp.min
Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')
>>> pd.Timestamp.max
Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```