# Representing a time interval with one bound set to "infinity"

Tags: python, pandas

For `float`-based dtypes, it's straightforward to create an `IntervalIndex` with "infinity" at one or both ends:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([-np.inf, -100, 0, 100, np.inf], closed="left")
print(intervals)
```

```
IntervalIndex([[-inf, -100.0), [-100.0, 0.0), [0.0, 100.0), [100.0, inf)], dtype='interval[float64, left]')
```

This is convenient, because now *any* real number (or its floating-point approximation) less than `-100` will be considered within the `[-inf, -100.0)` interval.

I now want to do the same for a `datetime64` interval index. That is, I want to create a leftmost and/or rightmost interval within the index that will represent *all* possible times in the past or future.

Naively I tried something like this:

```py
import pendulum

intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([-np.inf, pendulum.datetime(2020, 1, 1), pendulum.datetime(2022, 1, 1), np.inf])
```

but unsurprisingly it didn't work:

```
TypeError: category, object, and string subtypes are not supported for IntervalIndex
```

Is there some correct (and hopefully "dtype-native") way to represent such an interval?

I know that as a workaround, I can set a time very far in the past or future, as an approximation of infinity. Is that my only option here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a datetime ± infinity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356069/is-there-a-datetime-%c2%b1-infinity)

Comment: `datetime.datetime.max` / `datetime.datetime.min` or `pandas.Timestamp.min` / `pandas.Timestamp.max`

Comment: `datetime.datetime.min` did _not_ work (same `TypeError`), but `pd.Timestamp.min` _did_ work. I'd say the other question is very closely related but not a duplicate, if only because the answers are (slightly) different.

Comment: Fair enough - wasn't sure if it was a duplicate and didn't want to answer then have it closed. Anyhow will leave an answer to help others.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question as-asked appears to be "no", but there are hard-coded constants that can be used as suitably large values to approximate infinity.

As per [Is there a datetime ± infinity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22356069/2954547), the Python standard library defines constants for the min and max possible values for datetime objects.

Pandas defines analogous constants, `pd.Timestamp.min` and `pd.Timestamp.max`. Currently these values are `'1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193'` and `2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807`.

`pd.IntervalIndex` does not work with `datetime.datetime.min` (same error as in the question), presumably because it's far outside the Pandas representable range. However it works fine with `pd.Timestamp.min` and `pd.Timestamp.max`.

As long as your data does not extend contain dates outside of these ranges, these are suitable approximations of infinity.

Answer (score 1):

No but you should be able to use...

`pd.Timestamp.min` and `pd.Timestamp.max`

(which are `Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193')` and `Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')` respectively).

To represent the limits in your interval. Whilst these are not "infinities"  they represent the minimum and maximum Timestamp values that can be represented.

see: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.max.html

and

see: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.min.html